# Notation for surface integrals over vector fields

Tags: surface-integrals

Why do every question I see for a surface integral over a vector field $F$ under the surface $S$ be denoted by $$\int_{S} F \cdot n dS$$? As in, why does it only have a single integral? Where as once we expand the $dS$ to be $dudv$ (our parametric variables), we have a double integral? Shouldn't we have a double integral in the first place?

Comment: Some people do write it with a double integral sign ($\iint$). But many people (including myself) find it more elegant to use the single integral sign ($\int$). But you're right - whenever we evaluate a surface integral, we do need to perform a double integral.

Comment: In some texts, it **is** the convention to use a double integral sign for surface integrals, as in 
$$
\iint_S F \cdot n \, dS
$$

Comment: In a sense, we can think of **every** integral as really being a "single integral" with respect to some measure over some space.